# Recursively create directories in Carbon

Tags: macos, macos-carbon

I have tried CFURLEnumerator but it errors out telling me it cannot continue since my URL doesn't exist. Of course it doesn't exist, I'm trying to create it! So how could I recursively create a directory at a file path specified by CFURL.

PS: I already tried the file manager functions and those don't work recursively.

Comment: `[NSFileManager createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:]` failed to create the intermediates?

Comment: I need to use Carbon. No objective-c

Comment: Cocoa will do recursive creation, but you can't use it. Carbon's File Manager functions (`FSCreateDirectoryUnicode`) don't do recursive creation. The POSIX `mkdir(2)` doesn't do recursive creation. Seems to me like you either need to roll this yourself, or use the Cocoa function. Apple has some old documentation on [Using Cocoa in a Carbon Application](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CarbonCocoaDoc/Articles/WrapperFunctions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002398-DontLinkElementID_9)